# 2.5ns analogue beamformer (8 to 1 channel)

Tags: delay, ultrasound

I’m looking for a chip or system that can receive eight ultrasonic signals from 1 MHz up to 10 MHz, delay each channel with a set delay (minimum of 2,5ns and max 2,5us), combine them (sum or sum/avg) and send the combined (analogue) signal out again. This system should preferably be analogue, but if it must internally be digital the sampling rate should be sufficient to exclude under-sampling.[image: Analogue beamformer]

I would be very thankful if anyone of you knew such a system or a vendor that makes such products.

Comment: 'can receive eight ultrasonic signals' Are these signals really ultrasonic (i.e. soundwaves beyond the normal hearing range) or do you mean high frequency AC in the low radio frequency range?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant the signals received are ultrasonic and come from eight transducers. So the signals entering the chip/system are sinusoidal electronic waves with a frequency from 1 MHz up to 10 MHz

Comment: Note that if you can't find exactly the video delay lines you need, you can fine tune delays by adding calibrated lengths of coaxial cable (about 1.5 ns/foot). In the early days of colour TVs, studios used this technique to synchronise colour subcarrier phase to within about a nanosecond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the delays set or variable?
If they are set then you can use analog delay lines and add them together with a resistor network. Here are some examples http://micro.apitech.com/delay_lines.aspx, the switched coaxial delay lines are something that you might even be able to build yourself.

If the sensing arrangement would work and still be linear with the sensors in different positions you may be able to simply change the position of the sensors to introduce delay.

Otherwise you will need some very advanced equipment, something that can sample eight 10MHz signal at say 40MHz at even 8-bit accuracy will generate a data stream of 2.5Gb/s. You would need to program an FPGA unless you can find a bucket brigade type delay chip that can operate at several times your maximum frequency, if it exists it would be insanely expensive.

For combining the signals the easiest way is something like this:
[image]

Search op-amp adder for more details.

Comment: delays are variable in a sense that they should be initialized at the start-up of the system. So wont change during the run, but yes they are variable.
Preferably we want to buy something of the shelf so we can start using it asap. In my opinion building something that includes an FPGA wont be that hard, but it will take a lot of time.
Because of the big datastream we would like to have an analogue output of the summed/combined signal. This will later be processed by an existing tool.

Comment: And what would your guess be when you say extremely expensive? A few thousand dollar would be less expensive than having a few engineers waiting for half a year.

Comment: I can't think of any continuously variable solution other than programming an FPGA (one for each channel probably) although you could make a mercury delay line that is variable, they are surprisingly simple.

I'm sure there are products out there but not unless you have several thousand to drop on this.

Also I edited my post to show a simple adder you could use.

Comment: thanks for the help! I'm going to look into this!
Do you have any ideas what terminology I should use to search for those products or what vendors might have it?
I saw the edit, thanks for helping!

Comment: Ahhhh, just found that this is actually a commonly used product, for video! Search video delay line and you will come up with many off the shelf products, digital and analog, I am guessing some will be exactly what you are looking for, some of them are not even that expensive.